# Is there a reason chi square tests are used over normal tests in survival?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, survival, logrank-test

I've been reading and programming a bit about survival, and it seems that a lot of statistics are normally distributed (and thus, their square is chi square distributed). For example, the log rank test, and the wald test. But R often only computes the chi square statistic. Is there a reason for this (computational/practical/ect.), or did the creators of the survival package just prefer chi square over normal?